# Promise keeps pending and "then" or "catch" are not triggering. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, nodes

I'm catching up to learn React. If you have any tips on this code, please share, it is very important to me :).

Why this promise doesn't work?

In console show status pending.

**The promise:**

```
_server.get(`/select`, (req, res) => {   
        return DefaultSQL.select(table).then((result) => {           
            return result
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });      
})
```

**Where I call the promise:**

```
export const getData = (url) => {
  const response =  Server.get(url)       status
    return response.then((result) => {    // <- Not firing  
      return result 
  }).catch((err) => { // <- Not firing too
    console.log(err);
  })    
}
```

**What the promise call:**

```
class DefaultSQL {
  select(table) {
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM ${table}`;
    return Db.conn.query(sql).then((result) => 
      result
    ).catch((err) => {  
      console.log(err) 
    });
  }
...
```

**EDIT:**

When I change the "return result" to "return res.json(result)" the promise does not keep pending, **but where I call the promise gets a error saying that "response" is not a function**

Comment: It seems you are mixing up serverside code with clientside code. The route handler function on the server must write a response, not return a promise.

Comment: Show us your implementation of `Server.get`, please. That must be where the clientside error about `response` not being a function comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You should `rethrow the error/throw a new error` to `catch error again`.

It's an example:

```js
Promise.reject("throwed on demo 1")
.catch((e) => {
  console.log("Catched", e)
})
.catch((e) => {
  // unreached block
  console.log("Can NOT recatch", e)
})

Promise.reject("throwed on demo 2")
.catch((e) => {
  console.log("Catched", e)
  throw e
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.log("Recatched", e)
})
```

UPDATE: Another issue, you need to send a response even error/success. Otherwise, the request will not respond, the client will be pending forever.

```js
_server.get(`/select`, (req, res) => {   
        return DefaultSQL.select(table).then((result) => {           
            res.send(result)
            //return result
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send(err)
            console.log(err)
        });      
})
```

Comment: Where I do the reject?

Comment: Not you. `Db.conn.query(sql)` will reject when it has error.

Comment: I found the other issue on your code. I just have updated the post.

Comment: "res" is not reachable inside catch. There is a way to change status inside error?

Comment: "res" should available inside the `_server.get` scope. Inside DefaultSQL, please rethrow the error.